# function like onBackPressed() supportActionBar() import error after migrating to androidx

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, androidx

After migrating from `android.support` to `androidx`, all the functions like `onBackPressed()`, `setSupportActionBar` and other default functions has stopped working.
How to fix this error?[image: Imports from androidx]

[image: Imports from androidx giving error]

[image: Base activity]

Comment: could you please show us the code?

Comment: @ZaidMirza i have added the code

Comment: Paste the code from BaseActivity.

Comment: I am also getting same error :(

Comment: @ErnestZamelczyk i have pasted the baseActivity

Answer (score 1):

Dagger 2.17 isn't compatible with Androidx. Use 2.16

After changing version perform clean build and if it's still not working then perform `Invalidate Caches / Restart` from the `File` menu

Answer (score 0):

Ok. The issue was with dagger version 2.14. Which uses `support` version for `AppCompatActivity` instead of `androidx`. Upgrading to latest version of dagger will solve this problem

Answer (score -1):

We are using both these function will post code and a fancy onBackPressed fun

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_person)
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

    initViews()

}
```

Here is the Option Selected code we have a Menu here as well

```
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
    if (item != null) {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.addNote -> {
                val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("FROM","N")// ADD NEW NOTE
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
        // CODE below manages HOME Button
        val id = item.itemId
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("FROM","N")// ADD NEW NOTE
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

And now that fancy onBackPressed with GLOBAL TOAST

```
    override fun onBackPressed(){
    theTOAST()
}

fun theTOAST(){
    val toast = Toast.makeText(this@PersonActivity, "USE  <-- to go back",Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
    val view = toast.view
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
    val text = view.findViewById(android.R.id.message) as TextView
    text.setTextColor(Color.BLUE)
    text.textSize = (20F)
    toast.show()
}
```

To make the Toast Global you need a var toastSTR = "" at top level
Then put that var in the Toast where the string would go and set the value and call the fun wrom any fun you want a custom toast

Comment: please post your imports too